# Flutter Column CrossAxisAlignment.center not centering

Tags: flutter

I've been having this issue recently,
When Using

```
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('please'),),
          RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('center'),)
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Results in the children widgets aligning to the left

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n64eQ.png)
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is because Column does not takes all the space available horizontally. You can do it like this :

```
class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          body: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
             SizedBox(width : double.infinity),
              RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('please'),),
              RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('center'),)
            ],
          ),
        );
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Align()

like this:

```
    class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginPage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Align(
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('please'),),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('center'),)
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need to add extra widgets, just wrap your widget to the Center widget.

```
 return Scaffold(
  body: Center(
    child: Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('please'),),
        RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('center'),)
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

But I think you probably need some widgets.

If so, using the container widget.

```
return Scaffold(
  body: Container(
    child: Row(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
      children: [
        Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('please'),),
            RaisedButton(onPressed: (){}, child: Text('center'),)
          ],
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 0):

**For Row:**

mainAxisAlignment = Horizontal Axis

crossAxisAlignment = Vertical Axis

**For Column:**

mainAxisAlignment = Vertical Axis

crossAxisAlignment = Horizontal Axis

When you use a Row, its children are laid out in a row, which is horizontally. So a Row's main axis is horizontal. Using mainAxisAlignment in a Row lets you align the row's children horizontally (e.g. left, right). The cross axis to a Row's main axis is vertical. So using crossAxisAlignment in a Row lets you define, how its children are aligned vertically.

In a Column, it's the opposite. The children of a column are laid out vertically, from top to bottom (per default). So its main axis is vertical. This means, using mainAxisAlignment in a Column aligns its children vertically (e.g. top, bottom) and crossAxisAlignment defines how the children are aligned horizontally in that Column.

**Row/Column are associated to an axis:**

Horizontal for Row
Vertical for Column

mainAxisAlignment is how items are aligned on that axis. crossAxisAlignment is how items are aligned on the other axis.

for more details, you can read here[Flutter crossAxisAlignment vs mainAxisAlignment](https://champ96k.medium.com/flutter-crossaxisalignment-vs-mainaxisalignment-5cc220bc0e2c)

I hope its help :)

Answer (score 0):

**To understand the issue first let me explain:**

The column is only as wide as the child's width. This why you think nothing is happening "crossAxisAlignment"

To get Column children in the center of the screen, you can do this with many ways.

****Solutions:****

**Align**
wrap your Column or sometimes one of Column children with Align widget, which is by default using

```
alignment = Alignment.center
```

**Center**
wrap your Column with Center() widget fix the issue

```
Center(
child: Column(
mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
children: [...]
))
```

**Container**
You can wrap Column with SizedBox or Container

```
Container(
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [Text('Centered')],
        ),
      ),
```

**SizedBox**

*you can add SizedBox as child to Column with "double.infinity width"*

This will force Column to take all space of screen and give room to the other children to be centered

```
          Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [Text('Centered'), 
              SizedBox(width: double.infinity),
            ],
          ),
```

**SizedBox.expand**
You can use SizedBox.expand() with Column and Row, but be aware that may cause issues with **SingleChildScrollView()** and things like it

```
SizedBox.expand(
  child: Row(...),
),
```

**CrossAxisAlignment.stretch**
You can use stretch to make Column take all screen, I think some times this is useful and can be used

```
 Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
                mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
                children:[...]
)
```